# Package AIR Application (not installer) as a single EXE on Windows

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, air

When an AIR app is published, the result is an .air application installer. When this installer is run on a Mac, a single .app file is created, containing all the files needed to run the AIR app. When the .air installer is run on a PC, the result is a folder with several subfolders, an .exe, a .swf, and a mimetype file.

How do I make the Windows result more like the Mac result? That is, how does one create an AIR app for Windows where the result is a single .exe file, which bundles all the needed components?

I'm using Flash Professional, not FLEX or Flash Builder. Also, I don't need to bundle the AIR runtime or change the installation process at all. Installing from a .air file is fine. I just want to change the *result* of the installation.

Put another way, is there a means of distributing an AIR application for Windows, where the application is a single EXE. I don't care about the installation process at all — whatever it takes, I need the result to be one EXE that directly runs my application.

Comment: It's possible that MDM Zinc could accomplish this task, but I'd rather find a free and "standard" solution, if one exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's just how Windows OS works.

Mac is the same except the folder is hidden.  the .app "file" is actually a folder.  if you right-click on the .app file and select "show package contents" you'll have access to all the same files that you see in the Windows OS folder.

are you trying to lock up some files so they are not accessible, or are you just trying to offer a more Mac-like experience on Windows?

Comment: While the .app file is indeed a folder, it is also the entry point for the user into the application. That is, the application is wholly encapsulated by the .app file/folder on a Mac. On Windows, the entry point into the application is the .exe file, not the folder that contains it. I am, as you guessed, trying to hide the support files within the .exe itself. The executable must be freely moved and renamed, without breaking references to the files it depends on. Likewise, I can't just rely on a link from the Start Menu.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Just noticed the "(not installer)" part, so this is probably not what your after?

I have done something similar to this before.

The details of packaging an Air app as a single EXE are here:
http://bbishop.org/blog/?p=132

and to include the Air redistributable with the EXE
http://bbishop.org/blog/?p=220

Hope this is kind of what your after

Brian

Comment: No, sorry, this isn't what I'm after. I'd previously found your posts via google, and have read them several times over. Great stuff, but not a viable solution for my problem.